# How to create MY OWN custom icons 18.04

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

I want to create an icon pack for Ubuntu 18.04. Icon Theme? Icon set? I don't know the official term used with Ubuntu

I have my own personal .ico icons that I created to modify Windows with a while back, but now I'm using a computer running Ubuntu 18.04 and want to use it here. I'd also like to know where to search to see what all I need to create; from what I've seen icon packs can change more than just system icons

I know Ubuntu doesn't use .ico so I'll need to convert all of them to whatever it does use (I think just a 64x64 .png?)

I've spent quite a long time searching on Google for my answer, but the few search results that wern't "Install a pre-made theme" were posts made in 2012 or earlier; very outdated.

To be clear; I don't want to install a pre-made icon set. I want to make my own personal icon set for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: i suggest you to dowload a custom icon theme.. apply on your present Ubuntu.. then change the icons with your icons in the same format and same size.. once you understand this concept.. you can become master of it as you are already master in windows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the specifications that Gnome proposes for the creation of themes.

I leave you the link of: [Icon Theme Specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20201026043521/https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/)

You can search in a theme that you like in Github, or another repository, to see how make it and is built.